# AJAX global vars

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I'm trying to do this, which returns 'undefined':

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'curriculum/read_types',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(data) {
        return data;
    }
})
```

But if I do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'curriculum/read_types',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

it writes an entire JSON object on the console, so I know there exists data.

How I can return this data?

---

What I want to do is the next:

```
var curriculum = {
add : function() {
    html = [];

    html.push('<select name="type" required>');
    html.push('<option value="0">Grupo general...</option>');

    var types = curriculum.read_types();
    $.each(types, function(k,v) {
        html.push('<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>')
    })

    html.push('</select>');

    content.show('Añadir imagen a curriculum',html.join(''));
},
read_types : function() {
    $.getJSON('curriculum/read_types', function(data) {
        return data;
    })
}
}

curriculun.add()
```

---

Finally it managed but with a asyn:false request:

```
var curriculum = {
add : function() {
    html = [];
    html.push('<select name="type" required>');
    html.push('<option value="0">Grupo general...</option>');

    var types = curriculum.read_types();
    $.each(types, function(k,v) {
        html.push('<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>')
    })


    html.push('</select>')
    content.show('Añadir imagen a curriculum',html.join(''));
},
read_types : function() {
    var a;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'curriculum/read_types',
        type : 'GET',
        async : false,
        contentType : 'JSON',
        success : function(data) {
            a = data;
        }
    })
    return a;
}
}
```

Comment: `success` is a callback function, you can't return from it. You can work with JSON object inside the `success`.

Comment: return data to what? Typically you have a variable declared before the `ajax` call is made, then assign the data to that in the success handler if you need access to it.

Comment: Is this a typo - `return data:`? It should be `return data;`

Comment: You would have to do a synchronous AJAX call to do something like this, but I don't recommend it. It makes for unresponsive UIs.

Comment: As others mentioned, you don't return data from the callback. Instead, you *do* something with it. So you would modify the DOM, update a 'model' object, etc.

Comment: I've updated the first comment with more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, ajax is asynchronous. you could pass async false to force the javascript thread to wait, but this is just nasty and very non-javascript-like.
I interpret that it is something like this you want:

```
var myData;
$.ajax({
    url : 'curriculum/read_types',
    type : 'GET',
    async : false,
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(data) {
        myData = data;
    }
})

// while this is what you want to do, myData would be undefined here
console.log(myData);
```

But instead you should just continue doing what you did in the success-function.

Comment: Marcus, while it's clear to me what you're saying, you should emphasize that the code you've posted would result in a null or undefined error being thrown in the console statement. Others might not read carefully and might just look at the code. Other than that, you are correct that it is indeed a viable option to process the data inside the success handler. Good luck! :)

Comment: Is it an if(window.console) you are after, or is it the async-parameter that I've missunderstood?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, your answer is correct, it's just that the part about "continuing what you're doing" might be missed by others  that might just look at the code section, say to themselves. "myData is undefined in 'console.log' because it's firing before the success callback assigns data to myData'.  In other words, I don't want you to get downvoted for a "correct" answer that a fly-by-nighter might miss :)  Hope that helps.

Comment: I added a code comment above console.log. If I misunderstood or you think that misses the point of your answer, feel free to rollback my edit. :)

Comment: But what I want to do is impossible to do in the success function callback, I've added the entire code in the first comment. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Callback functions, like the success handler, are registered, asynchronous events that fire once the AJAX request is completed and returns successful results to the client browser. Since the event is registered, it doesn't block the function that you're AJAX request is in from running.

In order to process the data, simply hand off the data to another function, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'curriculum/read_types',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data):

        // process the results
        processData(data);
    }
});


function processData(data) {
    // do stuff with the data here
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
read_types : function() {
    $.getJSON('curriculum/read_types', function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

The above code is simply something you cannot do. Here is a loose description of the flow:

> - `read_types` function is called from some other process.
> - The $.getJSON function is called with 2 arguments: path and callback handler.
> - The read_types function finishes processing and reaches the end.
> - Next, while the read_types method is in the process of finishing up, the getJSON function makes an HTTP GET request to your URL.
> - The data is received in the response and passed to the callback handler as an argument assigned to the parameter "data".
> - When you call `return data;` you are returning data to the anonymous success callback function, not read_types. Thus, the return statement essentially does nothing.

### **Synchronous Request Example:**

Now, with that said, you can make synchronous requests to the server, but this is strongly discouraged because of the effects it has on the view.

However, here is an example, for academic purposes only. I would never advocate for using this strategy unless you really really really know what you are doing:

**NOTE: This is not to be used in production unless you know what you're doing!**

```
function getData() {

    var myDataObj = null;

    // this will BLOCK execution of all other scripts on the page until
     // the data is received!
    $.ajax({
        url : 'curriculum/read_types',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data):

            // we can assign this data to myDataObj in synchronous requests
            myDataObj = data;

        },
        async: false  /** Make a synchronous request **/
    });

    // Since we BLOCKED, this object is not null. If we used async: true 
     // (the default) then this would return null.
    return myDataObj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this inside a literal object. I mean: this is inside a function in a lit. object, where I must write the function?

Comment: Success callback functions are anonymous. They're not designed to return data. They're designed to accept data passed in from jQuery -- after the AJAX request completes -- and then hand that data off to a callback handler or process in some other way. AJAX is asynchronous, so it doesn't block other functions from running while we wait for the data. If it blocked, the entire page would "hang" while you wait for a response. This would be jarring to the user. With that said, if I misunderstood your question, consider updating your question with more details and examples. Good luck!

Comment: @Mario - I updated my answer with a synchronous example and described why this is harmful. You have to think about JavaScript differently due to it's asynchronous nature, if you want give your users a snappy user experience.

Comment: Ok, thank for your explanation but I don't know how can I do with asynchronous request, I know that do it through return is impossible so that what's the method, I'm really lost on this D:

Comment: Mario, look at the very first code example in my answer. You basically have to hand off control to another function. In your case, think of the AJAX request as the last thing your read_types function does, just hand the data off to another function that will then do the work.

Comment: Ok, I've done it but still not working (I've written the code in the first comment) I suppose it's because of the asynchoronous, does it mean that I would have to do sync? D: Thank you so much

Comment: @Mario - That looks like that should work to me, except just make sure your function definition for `a` is not inside a function. It should be defined at the global scope. Also, be sure to look at what is happening in your debugger. You can use console.log to trace the execution.

Comment: No, but I imagine the array html becomes full before the ajax request is completed so that these parts of the array are never added to html. I finally managed but with asyc: false. I've added the code ;)

Comment: @Mario - The main difference with async is that the user can still interact with other parts of the page that are still visible, even while the AJAX request is waiting for responses or while it's rendering data on the page. Glad you got this working! Good luck! :)

Comment: Yeah, I know but I think is the unique way to do it. You've really helped me. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asyncronous, so returning it does no good. You could use a custom event instead. In the success function:

```
$('#someelement').trigger('read_types_loaded', [data]);
```

Then attach an event listener somewhere:

```
$('#someelement').bind('read_types_loaded', function(event,data){
    // Do something with data
});
```

Comment: Creative! I will have to remember "trigger"! However, wouldn't it just be easier to just simply call a function in the success handler and pass the data that way instead of binding something to some arbitrary DOM element?

Comment: In this case, no doubt. In general, I just like to use events when working with asynchronous functions, to be sure the data is ready when the function is called. It makes debugging easier when you suddenly have a couple of asynchronous functions being called in succession, and stuff is breaking :)

Comment: Interesting. You should consider elaborating in your answer with an example. I'm not 100% sure I understand, but I'm interested to learn more. For instance, doesn't the success callback handler also wait until the data is ready before attempting to use the data? I'm not 100% sure I see the advantage when the latter method seems more commonplace yet still might achieve the same goals.

Comment: Sure, I'll see if I can come with something tomorrow! I'm on an iPad now, so it takes me like 30 minutes to write an answer like the above.